# Best way to implement aggregation in Go (like GROUP BY in SQL)?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a struct

```
type row struct {
    f1, f2, f3 string
    v int64
}
```

We can imagine it as a row in a table.

Also, I need to implement a function which does aggregation like this query:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3, SUM(v) FROM table GROUP BY f1, f2, f3
```

So, I have to implement function:

```
type key struct {
    f1, f2, f3 string
}
func aggregate(t []row) map[key]int64
```

or if can be

```
func aggregate(t []row) map[string]row
```

where map key is, for instance, f1+f2+f3

```
func aggregate(t []row)  []row
```

also works if result will include unique f1, f2, f3 combinations (DISTINCT f1, f2, f3)

I have two variants:

```
func aggregate1(t []row) map[key]int64 {
    res := map[key]int64{}
    for _, r := range t {
        res[key{r.f1, r.f2, r.f3}] += r.v
    }
    return res
}
func aggregate2(t []row) map[string]*row {
    res := map[string]*row{}
    for _, r := range t {
        var sb strings.Builder
        sb.WriteString(r.f1)
        sb.WriteString("#")
        sb.WriteString(r.f2)
        sb.WriteString("#")
        sb.WriteString(r.f3)
        id := sb.String()
        t := res[id]
        if t == nil {
            t = &row{f1: r.f1, f2: r.f2, f3: r.f3, v: 0}
            res[id] = t
        }
        t.v += r.v
    }
    return res
}
```

The first variant spends too much time in https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?m=all#mapassign (runtime.mapassign)

The idea of the second variant is to use faster https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?m=all#mapassign_faststr (runtime.mapassign_faststr), but strings.Builder.WriteString eliminates all benefits from runtime.mapassign_faststr :(

So, can you suggest more ideas about how to implement this aggregation?

I am thinking about how to efficiently calculate "id" in the second variant. It should be unique. My variant is unique because f1, f2 and f3 can't include "#" character.

Comment: We need data for the benchmark.

Comment: Have you tried pre-computing the map key as a single string and storing it as an additional field when the row object is created or modified?